# How to prove function $f_n(x)= \frac{x}{nx^{2}+1}$ converges uniformly?

Tags: uniform-convergence

For $n ∈ N$, define the formula,

$$f_n(x)= \dfrac{x}{nx^{2}+1}$$

Prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$, as $n \to\infty$.

I know that the definition says $f_n$ converges uniformly to f if given $∀ ϵ>0$, $∀ n≥N$, such that $\lvert f_n(x)−f(x)\rvert \lt \epsilon$, $\forall n \ge N$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb R$.

But I can´t find an $n≥N$ such that $|f_n(x)−f(x)|<ϵ $

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb N,\forall n\ge N,\forall x\in\Bbb R, \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert<\epsilon$.

Comment: First: find out what $f$ should be.

Answer (score 0):

HINT $1$: Compute the maximum of the generic term $f_n$ and see where it converges and, if such convergence is independent of $x$

HINT $2$: observe the puntual limit is $0$ and bound $f_n$ from above with a constant dependent of $n$ and independent of $x$